# What is TypeReference in java which is used while converting a JSON script to MAP

Tags: java, json

While converting a JSON received from api response I came accross TypeRef, but I am not sure how does it works? Any pictorial representation or simplified version will be good. I read, but still not so much clear about it.
Like we have map to store <K,V> but then what difference will TypeRef will do on object?

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {};
```

Comment: Which package does `TypeReference` belong to?

Comment: Are you using some library such as Jackson to process your JSON? The `TypeReference` class or interface is not bundled with Java, but may be present in a 3rd-party library. Voting to close as not providing enough debugging information.

Comment: Java's generics use type erasure to remove the type information. So in order jackson/gson be able to deserialize to the correct type they somehow need to obtain that info. The type information is preserved in sub-classes, so these frameworks force you to inherit some generic class in order to be able to extract that info via reflection ffrom the child class

Answer (score 11):

In Java generics are more or less gone at runtime. This is called type erasure. So your `HashMap<String, Object>` will just be `HashMap<?, ?>` when your programme runs. So Jackson cannot determine the types `String`and `Object`. That is why you have to create a `TypeReference` which will preserve that information at runtime so Jackson can deserialise your JSON String into the correct classes.

If you don't specify a type Jackson will still be able to correctly deserialise simple objects like `String` or numbers but when a more complex object is encountered it will simply deserialise them into `LinkedHashMap` which will then most likely lead to a `ClassCastException` when you try to access the deserialised object.

Answer (score 5):

This `TypeReference<T> implements Comparable<TypeReference<T>>` is part of `jackon` library. And this is part of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type`. From the [API documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

> This generic abstract class is used for obtaining full generics type
> information by sub-classing; it must be converted to ResolvedType
> implementation (implemented by JavaType from "databind" bundle) to be
> used. Class is based on ideas from
> http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html, Additional
> idea (from a suggestion made in comments of the article) is to require
> bogus implementation of Comparable (any such generic interface would
> do, as long as it forces a method with generic type to be
> implemented). to ensure that a Type argument is indeed given. Usage is
> by sub-classing: here is one way to instantiate reference to generic
> type List:
>
> TypeReference ref = new TypeReference<List>() { }; which
> can be passed to methods that accept TypeReference, or resolved using
> TypeFactory to obtain ResolvedType.

This is basically used to de-serialize the Generic type of JSON objects, for example the JAVA Collection objects as below:

```
public List<Double> getDoubleList() {

  return getObjectFromJson(new TypeReference<List<Double>>() {
  });
}


public <T> T getObjectFromJson(String jsonString, final TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
  try {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, typeReference);
  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    // TODO
  }
}
```

Comment: I am reading, processing and implementing all comments. Will get back once I get some inputs to go ahead.